# Explorer.exe locks created file --> access denied for Directory.Move

Tags: c#, windows

I have the following problem, and yes I browsed through the web for about 1 hour and found nothing that would solve my problem.

I have a folder with about 100 files in it, called "media". In my Delphi Setup.exe (also doesn't work in C#) I allow the user to make a backup of this "media" folder by simply rename it to whatever he wants, for example "media_v1". And it works just fine.

If I create a new file in this "media" folder, it can also be an empty txt, the rename process doesn't work anymore. The error "5 Access denied" appears.

Now, I looked for some help in the web and found out that it can be locked trough other process and so on. Fact:

Even Process Explorer doesn't show me any handles or dll that are locking any file, but if I kill the explorer task before, it works just fine again.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Directory.Move(@"D:media\folder", @"D:\media\folder_v1");
    }
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A Access Denied error message suggest that it is a permission issue. What is the OS? Post your C# code.

Comment: Please update. 1. Does the 'access denied' error occur for that new file only (probably yes)? 2. How is that file created?

Comment: It sounds like your code has errors.  If we could see your code we could probably help.  Please [edit] your question to show us what you are doing.

Comment: Don't think its a permission issue because it works after I kill the explorer, so the permissions are still the same.

The code looks as follow: (I posted it above cause it looks awfull donw here.
Its just a dummy code, but the error occurs also.

Comment: 1. It doesn't tell me which file causes the error but it occurs after the creation, so probably yes.
2. With the explorer himself, Right-click --> new --> txt

Comment: Just to get a clear picture: Do you get the error when you create a file via Code or with Explorer? If with explorer problem might not be related to any programming errors but simply OS level. Please confirm

Comment: I create the file with the explorer. And you're right, I don't think its an programming issue, but I don't know where to aks otherwise. Furthermore, I hoped that someone have experience with that kind of error.

Comment: What if you create a file in another directory? Do you get the same error? for example C:\AnotherDirectory

Comment: It works everywhere else.. don't know why..
But why would the explorer lock a special File/Directory?

Comment: Are you sure your code is not using that file in the directory?  Maybe code before the move takes place.

Comment: Very interesting hint! It works as long as there is no sub directory.. When i create a subdir or (if its an existing folder) a file in a subdir, then i doesn't work anymore..

Comment: And no there is no more code that that. I created a demo project for that reason with only this line.

Comment: so it works when there is no sub directories?

Comment: yeah, for some strange reason..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your approach is perfectly functional.  That this example works and yours does not implies that there is more to your code than you are showing us.  Something else you are doing is causing the problem.  Showing us the relevant code in your program is necessary.  Better yet, make an SSCCE yourself that demonstrates the problem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original Directory Contents  : ");
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test\stuff");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries) 
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);

        Console.WriteLine("Moving Directory... ");
        Directory.Move(@"C:\Test\stuff", @"C:\Test\stuff2");

        Console.WriteLine("Creating New File... ");
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\stuff2\new.txt", "test");

        Console.WriteLine("New Directory Contents  : ");
        fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test\stuff2");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);

        Console.WriteLine("Moving Directory... ");
        Directory.Move(@"C:\Test\stuff2", @"C:\Test\stuff");
        fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Test\stuff");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
    }
}
```

Output :

[image]

Repeating the test by replacing :

```
    Console.WriteLine("Creating New File... ");
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\stuff2\new.txt", "test");
```

with

```
    Console.ReadLine();
```

and manually creating a new text file in Explorer, then continuing the program also works without issue.

Comment: Good hint. But the code I posted is all the code there is. I created a demo Project for this reason. There is only this line.
Interesting fact: It works as long as there is no sub directory.. When i create a subdir or (if its an existing folder) a file in a existing subdir, then i doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @Michel I still can't reproduce your problem, unfortunately.  Your description is not very clear.  This needs a clear description of the exact steps needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its because the problem is difficult to describe^^... To reproduce on my side: Create a subfolder, create a file in there and then the move method for the top folder doesn't work anymore and the error "access denied" appears.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the problem Michel describes on Windows XP SP3 with latest patchlevel 05/2014.
I have many different PCs all suffering from that exact problem.

It must be a bug within Windows, because killing and restarting "explorer.exe" helps every single time.

Believe me, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Maybe explorer.exe suffers from some kind of handle leak.

I workaround this bug by killing and restarting explorer.exe within my scripts (ugly, but don't know any better way yet)

Maybe you can try an unlocker tool, that can free the handle.
Which OS did YOU use when you experienced the problem?